# How to make a neural network with multiple outputs (and multiple classes) using pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am working on a multi-output (i.e > 1 output target) multi-class (i.e > 1 class) (I believe this is also called a multi-task problem).
For example, my train_features_data is of shape (4, 6) (i.e three rows/examples and 6 columns/features), and my train_target_data is of shape (4, 3) (i.e 4 rows/examples and 3 columns/targets). For each target I have three different classes (-1, 0, 1).

I define an example model architecture (and data) for this problem like so:

```
import pandas as pd
from torch import nn 
from logging import log
import torch
feature_data = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'C': [9, 10, 11, 12],
    'D': [13, 14, 15, 16],
    'E': [17, 18, 19, 20],
    'F': [21, 22, 23, 24]
}

target_data = {
    'Col1': [1, -1, 0, 1],
    'Col2': [-1, 0, 1, -1],
    'Col3': [-1, 0, 1, 1]
}

# Create the DataFrame
train_feature_data = pd.DataFrame(feature_data) 
train_target_data = pd.DataFrame(target_data)
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

# create the model
class MyModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, inputs=6, l1=12, outputs=3):
      super().__init__()
      self.sequence = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(inputs, l1),
        nn.Linear(l1, outputs),
        nn.Softmax(dim=1)
    )
      
  def forward(self, x):
      x = self.sequence(x)
      return x
    
x_train = torch.tensor(train_feature_data.to_numpy()).type(torch.float)
model = MyModel(inputs = 6, l1 = 12, outputs = 3).to(device)
model(x_train.to(device=device))
```

When I pass my train data into the model (i.e when i call model(x_train.to(device=device))), I get back an array of shape (4, 3).

By following this resource [resource](https://www.learnpytorch.io/02_pytorch_classification/#83-creating-a-loss-function-and-optimizer-for-a-multi-class-pytorch-model), my expectation was that I would get a shape of like (4, 3, 3) whereby the first axis (i.e 4) is the number of examples in my features and targets data, the second axis (i.e the middle 3) represents the logits (or in this case because I have a softmax function, this will be the predicted probabilities) of each example (and this would be 3 because I have three classes), while the third axis (or rightmost 3 value in the shape) represents the number of outputs/columns I have in my train_target_data.

Can someone please provide some guidance on what I'm doing incorrectly here (if my approach is wrong) and how to go about fixing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model maps the input of shape `(4, 6)` to `(4, 12)` in the first linear layer, then to `(4, 3)` in the second layer.

If you want the output to be of shape `(4, 3, 3)`, you need to have the second layer output `(4, 3*3)`, then reshape.

```py
n_problems = 3
classes_per_problem = 3

model = nn.Linear(6, n_problems*classes_per_problem)

x = torch.randn(4, 6)
x1 = model(x)
bs, _ = x1.shape
x1 = x1.reshape(bs, classes_per_problem, n_problems)

y = torch.randint(high=classes_per_problem, size=(bs, n_problems))
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

loss = loss_function(x1, y)
```